# Why do I get different outputs while using ':' and '0' on a dimension (with size 1)?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I thought that the output of the last two statements (while using `:` compared to `0`) would be the same since there is only one dimension.

```
x = torch.arange(1,10).reshape(3,1,3)
x[:,:,2], x[:,0,2]

(tensor([[3],
         [6],
         [9]]),
tensor([3, 6, 9]))
```

Can anyone please explain to me the reason for different outputs?

Comment: Post your code here as text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

Your starting tensor is 3D and shaped `(3,1,3)`. The difference between the two indexing expressions is:

- in the former (`x[:,:,2]`), you select all elements from `dim=0` and `dim=1` *but only select* `i=2` on `dim=2`.
- Whereas, in the latter (`x[:,0,2]`), you select all elements from `dim=0`, but only select element `i=0` on `dim=1` and element `i=2` on `dim=2`. Since the selection on `dim=1` is a singleton, you are effectively **squeezing** one more dimension compared to the other expression.

As a result, the first expression results in a 2D tensor, while the 2nd expression returns a 1D tensor.

However, as you said, since we are only dealing with a single element on `dim=1`, then the resulting data is the same. It's just that the shape of the tensor is different. For demonstration purposes:

- `x[:,:,2][:,0]` is equivalent to just `x[:,0,2]` (squeezing `dim=1`),
- `x[:,0,2][:,None]` is equivalent to just `x[:,:,2]` (unsqueezing `dim=1`).